# Why does intentional buffer overflow not overwrite variable?

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

This may be a stupid question since I'm pretty sure this is impossible, but if it is please feel free to tell me what I'm doing wrong.
So I've been experimenting with buffer overflows and generally how memory works in C/C++ but I've encountered something very strange.

```
char arr[16];
char tmp = 33;

strcpy(arr, "AAAAAAAAAA3211f11f2gg233h4h34h43AAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");

cout << tmp << endl;
```

This code for some reason produces an "!" (which if casted to unsigned int is 33), and as I understand it, the *strcpy* call should have overflown *arr* and overriden *tmp* (or maybe even crashed the program as it is a pretty big string), but instead it does none of that.

```
cout << arr[20] << endl;
```

this code returns a "g" even though it's technically out of bounds.

Comment: Your code invokes Undefined Behavior, meaning - anything could happen: it could succeed, it could crash, it can do anything, and still be standard compliant.

Comment: Quote: "i've encountered something very strange" - yes, it even has a name: Undefined Behavior. Don't try to explain it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before giving the practical answer, I need to acknowledge the language lawyer answer:  Undefined behavior is undefined.  You asked about a unexpected result from undefined behavior, but there should be no expectations regarding the behavior of undefined behavior.

But the practical answer is stacks on typical architectures grow toward lower addresses.

So the practical expectation is that overrunning `arr[]` will trash the saved registers (likely including the return address) from the entry of the current function, so bad things will happen when this function tries to return.

But things allocated on the stack structurally later than `arr[]` will be at lower addresses and safe from the overrun.  In the most simplistic unoptimized compiler behavior, `tmp` is allocated later and lower than `arr` and so is safe.

The reason `tmp` is safe carries enough compiler assumptions that it would be absurd to predict `tmp` would be safe or to be surprised if `tmp` were not safe.  But `tmp` being safe is still a bit more likely than not in that code.  (The saved registers of the function getting trashed, is far more than "a bit more likely than not".  But even that isn't something you can trust will necessarily happen).

Comment: This answer just reminded me of a coworker that I have, that *fixed* a crash, by placing empty char array on the stack in a function..

Comment: Both at work and in online forums, I frequently find myself struggling to get other programmers to understand the basic fact:  The code change that eliminated the visible symptom of undefined behavior, did not fix the bug and is often very distant in both code and time from the bug.

Comment: Very informative, thank you for the information.
I found that declaring first *tmp* and then *arr* would acutally override *tmp*, so i have to ask:
If in the code above the overflow spills out to the variables declared before *arr* and there are none, is it possible to corrupt another process' memory? (And possibly crash that process)
And i understand that i should have no expectations from this kind of code, what im asking is if it is even possible to corrupt one process from another.

Comment: In practice, the OS rules separating processes take precedence over the C++ rules that undefined behavior can do **anything**.  No C++ language lawyer would agree, but in practice your other processes are safe.  Also, your assumption that no variables were declared "before" `arr` is not correct.  Variables declared in whatever function called this function are exposed to overrun of `arr`.  If this function is `main` you may not know some hidden function called it, but in fact it was called by part of the C++ run time library and you might be destroying that function's variables.

Comment: To really stretch theory over practice: There is some request this process could make to the OS to explicitly tell the OS to trash some other process.  In theory the undefined behavior within this process might be to make that request to the OS to trash another process.  So you need to draw some boundary between theory and practice before concluding your other processes are safe.  By definition, that boundary cannot be theoretically secure.

Comment: I assume youre talking about using shellcode in conjunction with one such overflow in order to trash a process from another?

Comment: No, I was not limiting that to shellcode.  For example, a process might have (or obtain) the right to write to the contents of another process's `/proc/PID` psuedo directory in Linux, and/or do the various things a debugger does when attaching to a running process.  Once your process has made itself the debugger of another process, almost any accident in your process harms the other.

Comment: Remember, a very likely thing trashed by the original bug is the return address of the current function.  Later that function returns executing a random jump to anywhere in your process's address space, where the code reached by that jump is then executed with garbage in place of its normal input and state data.  If that code happened to be the library routine for becoming debugger for another process, then that other process is suddenly at risk.

Comment: Remember also, in practice random jumps don't do that.  Most of your address space if filled with non code, so the random jump reaches something that will fault immediately.  If you hit code, most code uses references and pointers but all those will be random garbage, so it will promptly seg fault trying to use a bad address.  If you perfectly hit that debugger attach code I mentioned, it is nearly certain you try to attach to a process you lack rights for and still do no harm.  So the theory exists for that cross process trash, but in practice not.

Comment: And im going to guess there is no way to find out where this code is in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invoking Undefined Behaviour since you're writing to unallocated memory. Anything can happen, print a `'g'`, crash your box or your fridge could get raided! :)